# PHP Access Object Property with @ at the rate symbol

Tags: php, arrays, object, properties, symbols

An api is return an object with this structure,

```
[ABC] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [@total] => 149.66667
)
```

This is result in print_r function, how to access total's value, i have tried

```
ABC->@total
ABC->total
ABC['total']
ABC['@total']
```

but nothing works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap it into `{}`:

```
$ABC->{"@total"}; // here it needs to insert quotes as well
```

Also note that you have to prefix your class object with the dollar sign, this is the [link](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6adb08418368afd7fde09ad4ce43ad092ebd4122) to sandbox example.

Comment: Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$total